# MySQL \ regexp \ Search only the records which contains specific characters

Tags: mysql, regex

I would like to find all records from 'mytable' which in the field 'name' used only characters listed below:

```
Ø-*³`!/-;$€"“-    „”\ø,Ø:’.#*+_/?   !œ³¥Φ?+@=–()<>ąĄćĆęĘłŁńŃóÓśŚż      ŻźŹàáâåéÉêéíıñçãėÊèÈçßœŒæğîïİşúūýōòÒô
```

- regular letters from a to z (and A to Z)
- number 0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
- spaces and some 'tab' signs

This query does not work:

```
SELECT name
FROM mytable
WHERE name not regexp '[^a-zA-Z0-9Ø-*³`!/-;$€"“-    „”\ø,Ø:’.#*+_/?   !œ³¥Φ?+@=–()<>ąĄćĆęĘłŁńŃóÓśŚż  ŻźŹàáâåéÉêéíıñçãėÊèÈçßœŒæğîïİşúūýōòÒô]'
```

I know that this solution is far from good :) but I've tried different methods - this one returns the result closest to the required. Can you please give me some hint?

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of character classes.

For example, instead of `[ąĄóÓōòÒô...]` use `[[=A-Za-z=]]`.

This will match any letters from `a` through `z` igoring case and ignoring if the letter has accent.

Check the [documentation for additional characters classes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html) that will match your missing characters.